# Why color anomaly is in the axion photon coupling?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, axion

The axion photon coupling is given by the expression 
$ g_{a\gamma\gamma}= \frac{\alpha}{2\pi f_a}(\frac{E}{N}-\frac{2}{3}\frac{4m_d+m_u}{m_d+m_u}) $, where $f_a$ PQ symmetry breaking scale, $E$ and $N$ are the electromagnetic and color anomaly coefficient.

**My question :** why the color anomaly ($N$) is included in the first term of $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ ($\frac{\alpha}{2\pi f_a}(\frac{E}{N})$)?
In my understanding, this term arrises from the  anomaly (especially electromagnetic anomaly which is the first term of the following expression ) $\partial^{\mu}J_{\mu}^{PQ}=\frac{E\alpha}{4\pi}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \frac{N\alpha_s}{4\pi}Tr(G_{\mu\nu}G^{\mu\nu})$
So, it is not trivial for me that the color anomaly ($N$) is in the first term of $g_{a\gamma\gamma}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it appears due to a redefinition of the scale, $f_a = v_a/(2N)$ (see section 2.6 in this review by Di Luzio+: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01100).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert here, but does not the colour term constribute to the mass of the PQ axion and hence is part of the PQ symmetry breaking. If so one would expect to see it in the $m^2_a$ in
$$
(\nabla^2 +m^2_a)\theta= \alpha {\rm tr} \{F^2_{\rm Maxwell}\}
$$